# Detect any pagination in a conditional

Tags: categories, pagination, segments

I've got a site where it shows different content dependent on the url segments (categories eugh!) but as there can be up to 4 url segments, any of which could have pagination, i want to be able to say not if segment is a pagination segment.

Obviously i could do {if (segment_4 != '') && segment_4 != 'P25' && segment_4 != 'P50'} but pagination could be any value in theory. So, is there a way of saying "where segment_4 is not a pagination segment"?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [Switchee](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/switchee). It supports regular expressions, and example on devot:ee page shows how to use that to check for pagination.

Answer (score 5):

I use [Switchee](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/switchee) to detect pagination except in cases where I just can’t work Switchee into the template, in which case I use [MD Detect Page Type](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/md-detect-page-type).

Switchee example:

```
{exp:switchee variable = "{segment_4}" parse="inward"}
    {case value="''"}
        Not Paginated
    {/case}
    {case value="#^P(\d+)$#"}
        This is Paginated
    {/case}
{/exp:switchee}
```

MD Detect Page Type example:

```
{exp:md_detect_page_type url_segment="{segment_4}"}
    {if pagination_page == TRUE}
        Paginated
    {/if}
{/exp:md_detect_page_type}
```

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way is to use Rob's [Mo Variables](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/mo-variables) which comes with some very useful global variables for use in your templates including "{if paginated}". This also makes it very easy to see what the code is doing when you re-visit it at a later date.

Failing that I'd fall back to Switchee. -----

Comment: This is handy. I've used ```{if page_offset == 0}...{/if} ``` to distinguish the first page of a pagination set from the rest of the pages of that set as well.

Answer (score 2):

Switchee will work in some cases, but I've also been using the very versatile [Mo'variables](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/mo-variables) successfully. Among other things, it has a handy {if_paginated} conditional that checks whether pagination appears in your segments. Pleanty of other goodies as well in terms of working with segments.

EDIT: code example (not at my desk so cannot test)

```
{if segment_4 != ""}
    {if not_paginated}
        stuff to do
    {/if}
{/if}
```

When working with categories, I have also found [GWcode Categories](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/mo-variables) to be invaluable. Makes your life a hell of a lot easier.

Comment: Ha, beat me to the trigger. :)

Comment: I have been trying it, but it's not working as expected in my scenario. I want to do:
{if (segment_4 != '') && segment_4 not_paginate} but any combo i've tried hasn't worked. Any ideas on how to modify this tag to work with the mo variable ext?

Comment: I think mo'variables conditionals are simple ones, meaning I don't think they can be used like you suggest here. Have you tried a nested approach? Updated my answer with code.

Comment: Hmm, i don't think this is going to work in my scenario, i'm going to have to go for switchee i think. Thanks though, really appreciate your input!!